# determine google maps marker display status

Tags: api, maps

Straight from the google reference material on their API

Hiding a set of map markers previously plotted to hide

```
mapArray[i].setMap(null);
```

Simple.

However is there anything that will allow me to asses the display status of a marker thus allowing me to simply toggle the display status?

I've been googling it and searching their api refs but cannot see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try `google.maps.Marker.getMap()`.